# The velocity time graph of a particle moving along a straight line is shown in the following figure

Tags: graphing-functions

If a particle starts its motion from x=-4m, then which one represents the a-t graph?

The first figure is the question figure, the second figure contains the answer, and the third one contains the other options. 
[image: Question figure]

Options[image: Why is this the right answer]

Why is this the right answer [image: why are these the wrong answers]

Why are these the wrong answers?

Comment: Tried, still can’t understand.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: In your figure--the one that has the velocity graph that is the question, what is the **slope** of the graph, first for $t$ in the interval $(0,2)$, then for $t$ in the interval $(2,4)$.

HINT 2: The slope of a line segment from say $[0,2]$ is always a constant i.e., it is the same at $1/2$ as it is at $3/2$.

Comment: +2 and -2. Thanks, although I am still not sure about the x=-4m. It’s probably irrelevant, but I had to make sure.

Comment: As the particle's velocity from $t=4$ onward stays the same, the acceleration from $t=4$ onward is 0.